# Doing a mysql dump causes swapping issues

Tags: mysql, backup

I do a mysqldump manually every night.

I just noticed that after it is done and I try to access the website it is very slow. After I take a look at the free -mh I notice that the server is now swapping when it otherwise wasn't before the mysqldump.

What am I to do in this case? Just restart the server every time I backup? That doesn't seem very effective.

My database file raw is 1.1gb after the dump.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We dump much larger MySQL databases nightly without any swapping issues. Here is the command line that is executed:

mysqldump --host=$HOST -u $USER --password=$PASSWORD --max_allowed_packet=512M --port=3306 --single-transaction --skip-add-locks --quick -e databasename

Are you including the "--quick" option? This prevents mysqldump from retrieving large tables in a single query. This could be what is forcing your server to swap. It makes mysqldump get the large tables row by row.

Comment: Is it possible that it's also the "max_allowed_packet" part as well? Is there a way to force it to not use swapping?

Comment: You can eliminate the max_allowed_packet, or lower the value. We use because of the '-e' option for extended inserts in combination with some large data rows we don't want the dump to crash because of a large row. If your data row size is small and fixed, you can lower that value to close to the max size of the row.

You can eliminate the '-e' option as well. That may lower memory usage, but will result in larger dump files.

Swapping is a function of the OS, and the memory needed by running processes. There is nothing you can set wrt mysqldump to eliminate swapping from ever happening.

Comment: how large is "large"? is a 100MB table (in sql dump) large or are we talking about GB scale?

Comment: We end up with 50+ GB dump files

Comment: @Craig I know this is really old but having the same issue. How did you calculate the 512M max_allowed_packet size? Is it based on available RAM?

Comment: @robjbrain (Caveat: It's been 4+ years since I've messed with this stuff) The value defaults to 1GB. How to set it is kind of a black art. Generally, we set it to 10 times the size of our largest table row. It is memory allocated on the server to buffer MySQL packets between the server and client. Unless you have unusually large row size in one or more of your tables, the default should work. Just make sure it's larger than your largest row size.

Comment: cheers for the speedy response, will experiment a bit :)

Comment: "--skip-add-locks" option is redundant when using "--single-transaction" because "--single-transaction" and "--lock-tables" are mutually exclusive and "--lock-tables" is opposite to "--skip-add-locks". See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

Comment: Note that `--quick` is now enabled by default in recent versions of `mysqldump`

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the --quick option for mysqldump, the server will buffer the entire response before sending it to the client, which could easily cause swapping with large tables.

Also, if you save the dump to the host running the server it may fight mysqld for cache.  Try using --quick and running mysqldump over the network, if you're not doing these two things already.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Mysqldump lock all necesary tables while backuping, try using mysqlhotcopy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mysqldump might be loading much more data into caches than necessary. Anyway, if your server swaps, you probably have your cache values set too high.

Try running `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` before and after the dump, and compare values

Also, try restarting mysql after the dump. If that helps, it could be cache related